# Code not displaying count in identified range

Tags: vba

I have a workbook with 2 constant worksheets "Hourly" and "Daily"
we have employees that are paid on a hourly, or daily basis. I've created a macro that will import the timesheets behind the correct tab. I'm using the indirect function to display the hours or days they have worked on the "Hourly" or "Daily" payroll summary. the indirect formula matches the employee name on the payroll sheet with the sheet name for the time sheet. The purpose of the loop is to count the sheets behind the "Hourly" or "Daily" Summary so I can compare the populated payroll summary with the amount of time sheets imported and using conditional formatting make sure the payroll summaries count is equal to the amount of timesheets imported.

I am new to VBA and I am Very Great full for your help!

Not sure what the problem is here, the code compiles fine and seems to run fine but it is not displaying the count in the identified range. Any assistance is very much appreciated.

```
Sub CountWs()

    Dim i As Integer
Do While i = Worksheets("Hourly").Index + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Houly").Range("G6") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Exit Do
Loop
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: you never give a value to `i` so it is `0` and since the worksheet.index can never be `0` it never goes into the loop.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include what you are trying to accomplish with the code.  It will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Add a `debug.print i` into the loop, and watch the immediate window.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is due to a typo.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Houly").Range("G6") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hourly").Index` No loop needed.

Comment: What would cause Subscript out of range Error? I've double checked all spelling and made sure the workbook, and worksheets locked?

Comment: opps: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hourly").Range("G6") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hourly").Index`  I has missspelled `Hourly` in one of the references.

Comment: Thank You Everyone for your time! Scott where do I send your Coke Zero?!